# If a bond has a par value of 1000 and a monthly coupon rate of 3.650%, do I get $36.5 every month until maturity?

Tags: united-states, bonds, bond-coupons

I'm looking at bond with CUSIP DSDB66702, which has a monthly coupon rate of 3.650 and a par value of $1000. If I hold this to maturity will I get $36.50 every month before taxes?

Answer (score 5):

$36.50 * 12 = $438.00
If you give this a bit of thought, in the US rates are sub 5%/year, not 44%/year.

The coupon rate is an annual rate, so you get $36.50 total each year.